Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Didn't find class "dwfd" on path DexPathList
I'm encountering a crash on a device running Android 7. The crash is caused by a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to resolve the class dwfd. Below is the stack trace:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError  

Failed resolution of: Ldwfd;  

anun.d (:com.google.android.gms@243834000@24.38.34 (040300-681941525):5)
  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException  
Didn't find class "dwfd" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file 
"/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file 
"/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/split_config.ro.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.google.android.gms- 
1/split_config.xhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=. 
[/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.google.android.gms- 
1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.google.android.gms- 
1/split_config.ro.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.google.android.gms- 
1/split_config.xhdpi.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve it?

I'm guessing Ldwfd is an encrypted class name by proguard and the crash happened in a release version of the app?
if so, that is a fairly popular issue, I think there was a way to "decode" the name of the class that was missing / removed when building the release version (that was deemed "not used"), but in our case the classes were mostly things like API data classes etc. so try to add a @Keep annotation to them
